# Need to set java8 in codenameone project with IDE Myeclipse 2015

Tags: java, codenameone

I need to set java 1.8 in my codenameone project with IDE MyEclipse2015.

I have follow the guidlines from "https://www.codenameone.com/blog/java-8-support.html" and set project build path as java1.8 , compiler as java 1.8 and build.xml javac source and target as 1.8.

Also set build hint as java.version=8

Codenameone Version using 3.5 and refreshed cn1libs also.

```
 [javac] javac: invalid target release: 1.8
 [javac] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

Still I am getting error while send IOS app store build.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That generally means Eclipse is running under an older version of Java. You need to update the [eclipse.ini file](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) to use Java 8 for running Eclipse itself. Make sure you are using the latest version of the Codename One plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Or put the newest JDK-path to your %PATH% systemvariable, also create a %JAVA_HOME% and reboot your system

e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\`

[image: Eclipse JDK Setup]

[image: JAVA_HOME Path Variable]

[image: Path Variable]